# Picasso not working in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Inside my profile_fragment, I'm trying to load a image from a url to a imageView in a fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View Layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) Layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
    Picasso.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(imageUri).fit().into(imageView);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}
```

But the image won't load, the page is left blank.

And yes the internet permission are set in the manifest file. I'm using a login system

Comment: return Layout instead of return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

Comment: This helped Thanks!! @Opriday

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should **`return`** ***View's Object*** below way.

Try this way,

```
 View viewOBJ = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewOBJ.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri).fit().into(imageView);
        return viewOBJ;
    }
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 String imageUri = "https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg";

 Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
                        builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            if (!strProfileImage.equals("")) {
                                builder.build()
                                        .load(imageUri )
                                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.personal_pic)
                                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                        .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess() {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError() {
                                                // Try again online if cache failed
                                                Picasso.with(context)
                                                        .load(imageUri)
                                                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.personal_pic)
                                                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                                        .into(imageView);
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getStackTrace();
                        }
```

Hope this may help you